# Applying Cauchy's Integral Formula for $\oint_{|z|=4} \frac{e^{1 /(z-1)}}{z-2} d z$

Tags: complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

So, here is a problem:

$\oint_{|z|=4} \frac{e^{1 /(z-1)}}{z-2} d z$

the answer is $2i$

I cant understand what I am doing wrong:

Cauchy's Integral Formula:

$f(a)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z-a} d z$

In this case:

$f(a) = \{a=2\} = \exp(\frac{1}{2-1}) = \exp(1)$

Thus

$\oint_{|z|=4} \frac{e^{1 /(z-1)}}{z-2} d z = 2 \pi i exp(1)$

???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot apply Cauchy's integral formula here because $\exp\left(\frac1{z-1}\right)$ is *not* analytic on $\overline{D(0,4)}$. So, it is natural that it does no provide the correct answer. I suggest that you try the residue theorem instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Please, can you help further? According to the residue theorem, I should expand exp(1/(z-1)) in Laurent series at point 1 and take the first term of it which is a residue. But it seems to me that I cant expand the function at this point, at least, wolfram tells me that series is not available. What should I do?

Comment: It is very easy to get the Laurent series of $\exp\left(\frac1{z-1}\right)$ centered at $1$: it is$$1+\frac1{z-1}+\frac1{2!(z-1)^2}+\frac1{3!(z-1)^3}+\cdots$$What is not easy is to compute the Laurent series of $\frac1{z-2}\exp\left(\frac1{z-1}\right)$ centered at $1$. Anyway, I suggest that you post this as another question.